# How can I send some http request from postgresql function or trigger

Tags: postgresql, httprequest, plpgsql

I need to send data via http protocol (GET or POST request) from the function or trigger.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could try writing the trigger in PL/Python and use urllib2 to POST.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like a PL/Perl in untrusted mode (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/plperl-trusted.html)...

Are there differences in the use of PL/Python and PL/Perl? Both of then must be runned in untrusted mode and thats all? 

This means that I can use the module IO::Socket or HTTP::Request without any limitations?

Answer (score 11):

There is an extension to do this, use with caution.

[pgsql-http](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http)

Comment: Is it trusted extention?

Comment: @valijon I know this is too late; but it seems like the author of it is a postgis core contributor. So, I guess it's trusted?

Answer (score 4):

Any "untrusted" language with HTTP support can do this:

- PL/Pythonu
- PL/perlu
- PL/javau
- ...

but you shouldn't really do it. See [Does PLV8 support making http calls to other servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666148/does-plv8-support-making-http-calls-to-other-servers/) and [why you shouldn't send email from a trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002662/psql-trigger-send-email/12003516#12003516).