# How can I send email from PostgreSQL trigger?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

I using pgsql to set a trigger, when update the table dataset(change the status to Finished)
it will automatic send a email to the email account using dataset email value and save this email in server

but i don't know how to write in trigger function to send email, and send email in server.
Thank you in advance

Pg version is 9.1, and CentOS 5.8

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sss()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$begin
if(NEW.publisher== 'aaaa')
then
//send email and save to server 192.168.171.64
end if;
return NEW;
end

$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION sss()
OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION sss() TO postgres;
```

Comment: When asking questions about Pg it's really helpful to explain a little about your setup, in particular your Pg version. Different versions have different features, so the version may affect the answers.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

See [the excellent-as-usual depesz article](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/13/how-to-send-mail-from-database/), and [pg-message-queue](http://code.google.com/p/pg-message-queue/).

Sending email directly from the database may not be a great idea. What if DNS resolution is slow and everything hangs for 30 seconds then times out? What if your mail server is having a wobbly and takes 5 *minutes* to accept messages? You'll get database sessions hung up in your trigger until you're at `max_connections` and suddenly you can't do anything but wait or start manually cancelling transactions.

What I'd recommend is having your trigger [`NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) a [`LISTEN`ing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html) helper script that remains permanently running and connected to the DB (but not in a transaction).

All your trigger has to do is `INSERT` a row into a queue table and send a `NOTIFY`. Your script gets the `NOTIFY` message because it has registered to `LISTEN` for it, examines the queue table, and does the rest.

You can write the helper program in whatever language is convenient; I usually use Python with `psycopg2`.

That script can send the email based on information it finds in the database. You don't have to do all the ugly text formatting in PL/PgSQL, you can substitute things into a template in a more powerful scripting language instead, and just fetch the variable data from the database when a `NOTIFY` comes in.

With this approach your helper can send each message and only then remove the info from the queue table. That way if there are transient problems with your mail system that causes sending to fail, you haven't lost the info and can continue to attempt to send it until you succeed.

If you really must do this in the database, see [PgMail](http://brandolabs.com/pgmail).

Comment: @JesseSiu You seem to have copied and pasted this comment from another you posted an hour ago on a different answer. This answer has nothing to do with PL/Perl, and I do not recommend that you use it for the reasons explained in my answer. Use a script running *outside* the database to send mail.

Comment: @JesseSiu If you didn't understand the advice above, or it won't work for you, feel free to explain or ask for clarification, I'm happy to help. I just think you're taking the wrong approach.

Comment: I actually wrote pg-message-queue specifically so it would be an answer to this question.

Answer (score 7):

1. Use a local MTA (this gives you centralized SMTP config for multiple apps)
2. Have the local MTA relay to your real MTA (this gives you async support, essentially)
3. If windows, use blat SMTP command line client. Make sure the path to blat is in the PATH
4. You should probably do this using Apache Camel or pgAgent, and not directly in a trigger

This will work on Windows if postgres superuser. Trigger function should be SECURITY DEFINER. Similar for sendmail on Linux:

```
...

copy 
  ( select 'my email body' ) 
to program 
  'blat -to to@example.com -from from@example.com -subject "My Subject" -server localhost:25' 
with (
  format text
);

...
```

~ 60 ms

Comment: That's exactly the solution I was looking for, too bad "to program" is only available since PostgreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plperlu to send mail.

[This](http://evilrouters.net/2008/02/01/send-email-from-postgresql/) link shows an example of how to use it on a trigger.

Comment: Thanks, but the language is plpgsql, and when i type use Mail :: Sendmail; it shows syntax error

Comment: @JesseSiu You have to `CREATE LANGUAGE plperlu;` as a superuser before you can use it, and use `LANGUAGE 'plperlu';`.

Comment: when i type createlang plperlu mydb. it say could not open extension control file.  in the extension folder, it doesn't contain plperlu.control file ? how can i do

Comment: @JesseSiu That depends entirely on how you installed PostgreSQL. You still haven't updated your answer from two days ago when I asked you to add your Pg version. Maybe you should do that, and explain what OS you're on and how you installed Pg while you're at it? Once that information is available, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: sorry, i forgot add information. Pg version is 9.1, and CentOS 5.8

Comment: hi i using your method, but an error has occurred Can't locate Mail/Sendmail.pm in @INC(@INC contains: /usr/.... can you see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243335/pl-perl-send-mail-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You have the possibility to use pgMail (if you are allowed to install it):

If you follow the instructions on [brandolabs.com](http://brandolabs.com/pgmail) it comes down to

```
pgmail('Send From ','Send To ','Subject goes here','Message body here.')
```

Comment: can i use another way without install pgmail?

Comment: You can use this (with installing the program) or use the plperlu program from the post below.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Craig Ringer. You could code something in Python under 100 lines of code. I would recommend using the following Python libraries: psycopg2, smtplib. Depending on how often you would like to get notified of the changes, you could run a cronjob (depending on your working environment). That way you can aggregate multiple changes to the database into a single email rather than sending a notification every time a change takes place.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TypeScript/Node, then use the battle-tested [graphile-worker codebase](https://github.com/graphile/worker) to communicate from Postgres to Node. Then you can easily use your standard email logic in Node to send a email.