# ERROR: schema "utl_http" does not exist (In Postgres DB)

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating procedures & functions from Oracle-to-Postgres. However I am facing below issue when creating function in postgres.

> ERROR: schema "utl_http" does not exist 
>   LINE 5: L_HTTP_REQUEST UTL_HTTP.REQ;
>   ^ SQL state: 3F000 
>   Character: 303

To me it seems there should be some http extension plug-in which we are not having. Or Is there any alternative packagefor `UTL_HTTP.REQ`, `UTL_HTTP.RESP`, `UTL_HTTP.HTML_PIECES`, and so on.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wallet_active ( login_session text, source_wallet text, target_wallet text, Comment text ) RETURNS varchar AS $body$
DECLARE
--Declare
    L1_HTTP_REQUEST UTL_HTTP.REQ;
    L2_HTTP_RESPONSE UTL_HTTP.RESP;
```

I am looking resolution of UTL_HTTP package in postgres or any alternate package.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use the [pgsql-http](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http) extension, or you can write your own small function in PL/Perl - but you are advised to consider different option(s). See why [you should not send emails from your trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003516).