# Send email with attachment from postgres

Tags: postgresql

Thanks for reading the Question.

I am looking to send an email with an attachment from Postgres. The same is very simple when sending email from Oracle DB. I want to send an email directly from Postgres. Have anyone of you tried it and doing it successfully.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002662/how-can-i-send-email-from-postgresql-trigger

Comment: I am sorry, I read your link and it is not useful. I am using AWS Postgres 12.2 RDS instance. I am looking to send email from Postgres by using a function. The same thing in oracle is very easy to accomplish. It very beautifully explains in oracle. https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/utl_mail-send-email-from-the-oracle-database