# Does PLV8 support making http calls to other servers?

Tags: postgresql, plv8

If I write a function for PostgreSql using PLV8, can I call an url with a get/post request from my PLV8 function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to [this page](http://pgxn.org/dist/plv8/doc/plv8.html) and my understanding of "trusted":

> PL/v8 is a *trusted* procedural language that is safe to use, fast to run and easy to develop, powered by V8 JavaScript Engine.

Comment: Yes; I think this is correct.  However, it's a shame there is not a way to configure PostgreSQL and/or PLV8 to allow GET/POST requests to a set of "trusted" URLs.  Seems like you could do some very cool stuff (probably some pretty dangerous stuff also) lol

Comment: Thanks! I was not sure if http get/put calls is a part of the javascript language libraries, but it would not matter as long as the trusted status is there.

Answer (score 10):

No, as explained by Milen; use an untrusted PL like PL/perlu, PL/pythonu, PL/javau, etc.

Doing this has the same problem as [sending email from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12003516/398670), in that unexpected issues like DNS configuration problems could leave all your database connections busy waiting on HTTP connection attempts so nothing else can get any work done.

Instead, use [`LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) to wake an external helper script that uses a queue table to manage the requests, as explained in the answer linked above.

Comment: Thanks Craig, my requirements are a bit different then simply sending an email. In fact, I actually need the whole application to stop if postgresql can't successfully execute this connection. I agree with everything in the e-mail discussion, but this is a different case :)

Comment: @sarikan Yeah, if you need the whole app to stop then making a synchronous HTTP request from a Pg database worker (and repeating until they're all stuck) will do that! I never imagined someone might want that as a *feature* but hey, if it solves your problem...