# How to import or sync data to Neo4?

Tags: postgresql, neo4j, cypher

I have a REST API around a PostgreSQL database, the API was built using the Django REST Framework (python). I have access to the PostgreSQL database and the API, but I'm not allowed to modify the django/python code.

My first approach is to make, kind of, an HTTP POST request via a trigger every time a new record is created in PostgreSQL. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325292/how-can-i-send-some-http-request-from-postgresql-function-or-trigger) but seems like it's not the best way to do what I need.

In the Neo4j side, I'm thinking of a periodic HTTP GET request to the API from within a cypher function, but does not exist such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [APOC procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/database-integration/load-jdbc/) for integrating with other DBs via JDBC. PostgreSQL is supported.

You can also use APOC procedures like `apoc.periodic.schedule` or `apoc.periodic.countdown` to periodically execute a Cypher query in the background.