# How to handle database changes on Symfony

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

i have a nice question. I use Symfony to create an web application that works with contact-center telephony. 
Phone stations send data in postgresql database into one table when the operator speaks with clienty.

**The objective**: handle when the new row is put into table and inject it all into Symfony controller or anything that has Symfony context, because with arrived new data must be some manipulations. 
Please help me, i am sure someone faced with that before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can start with creating a trigger for insert in the database that calls an action in your symfony project, that does what you need.

refer to this question for http requests in postgresql:
[How can I send some http request from postgresql function or trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325292/how-can-i-send-some-http-request-from-postgresql-function-or-trigger)