# Invoke a lambda function from a PostgresSQL trigger

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a server built with [sam local start-api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html) using a PostgreSQL database running in a Docker container.

I'd like to invoke a lambda function that sends emails via AWS SES on the execution of a trigger in the PostgreSQL database. Is this something possible to achieve?

Comment: Make an HTTP request from [PL/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325292/how-can-i-send-some-http-request-from-postgresql-function-or-trigger) to API Gateway fronting Lambda?

Comment: Sounds interesting @jarmod. Do you have any resource that shows this more in detail?

Comment: You can do this from RDS PostgreSQL instances already (see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/amazon-rds-postgresql-integrates-aws-lambda/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html)) via SPs or UDFs.